# Who cut the coat - an idiom, a metaphor?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

> Frequently I have to ask myself in the street for the name of the man I bowed to just now, and then, before I can answer, the wind of the first corner blows him from my memory. I have a theory, however, that those puzzling faces, which pass before I can see **who cut the coat**, all belong to club waiters.

(from *The Inconsiderate Waiter* by James M. Barrie)

Can you explain what "who cut the coat" means in this passage?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think it might literally mean "who made the coat (that the man is wearing)".  I have never read *The Inconsiderate Waiter*, but I see that it is described as "a humorous take on the British class system of 1898", and a high-class British man of 1898 might be very interested in who made someone's coat, because it would be a sign of what social class they were from.

Comment: Discussed elsewhere 10 years ago. https://forum.thefreedictionary.com/postst207843_cut-the-coat-.aspxConclusion  "I dunno"